# How is everyone going with their/his/her assignment?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I wanted to email a group of students to check how they are going with their assignment and it occurred to me that "*how is everyone going with their assignment*" does not seem grammatically correct. Matching a singular subject "*everyone*" with a plural word "*their*" seems a bit odd. However, "how is everyone going with his/her assignment" sounds more off.

Thanks heaps! Any comment would be highly appreciated.

Wen

Comment: See the previous article; [Mark Nichol uses 'singular their' and puts up with / responds to the flak](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/is-%E2%80%9Cthey%E2%80%9D-acceptable-as-a-singular-pronoun/).

Answer (score 1):

Could you remove this confusion by going for the simpler

> How is everyone going with ***the*** assignment?

It should be clear what you mean with this email.

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole sentence sounds off to begin with. How can one "go" with an assignment in the first place? Perhaps I'm just not familiar with the expression.

***Everyone*** in this context is a second person pronoun, and it doesn't make sense to speak to someone (or a group of someone) in the second person and then refer to them with third person pronouns (his/her).

Perhaps one of these alternatives:

```
How is everyone doing with the assignment?
How is everyone's assignment going?
How is everyone doing with your assignments?
```

Note that with the last example, the actual second person point of view is consistent throughout.

The confusion comes from the fact that ***everyone*** can be either a third or second-person pronoun. You're using it as a second-person pronoun in this case, but then trying to follow it up with third person pronouns which you can't do.

Comment: "How is everyone doing with your assignments?" sounds a bit cumbersome. The first would be my choice.

Comment: @Ronan I agree that it is cumbersome, but it demonstrates the proper pronoun usage which is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: @leigero Thanks for your answer! I have always under the impression that "*How are you doing?*" and "*How are you going? (or How is it going?)*" are used interchangeably. Perhaps they are interchangeable only when used alone?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're addressing a group of young people via an informal means of communication, you could substitute the 2nd person plural ["you guys"](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=383) for "everybody," and say:

> How are you guys doing with your assignment?